# windeployqt fails with anaconda python

Tags: python-2.7, qt, c++11, qt5, anaconda

Some days ago I installed [Anaconda2](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows) python, version 4.2.0 32bit (Anaconda2-4.2.0-Windows-x86.exe). Then I uninstalled [python](https://www.python.org/) (python-2.7.13.msi).

After some tests I find [`windeployqt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) fails with Anaconda python. I'll show below the results of each.

Using `python-2.7.13.msi`:

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>>
>>> environ          = os.environ.copy()
>>> environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join(['C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/mingw482_32/bin',
...                                                  'C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/bin'])
>>>
>>> subprocess.call(['C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/mingw482_32/bin/windeployqt',
...                  'release'], env=environ)
C:\Users\User\Downloads\git-dev\myapp\archive\MyApp-1.2-20170224083154\source\build\release\MyApp.exe 32 bit, release executable
Skipping plugin qtaccessiblequick.dll due to disabled dependencies.
Adding Qt5Svg for qsvgicon.dll
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Widgets
All dependencies   : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Widgets
To be deployed     : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Svg Qt5Widgets
Updating icuin52.dll.
Updating icuuc52.dll.
Updating icudt52.dll.
Updating Qt5Core.dll.
Updating Qt5Gui.dll.
Updating Qt5Network.dll.
Updating Qt5Sql.dll.
Updating Qt5Svg.dll.
Updating Qt5Widgets.dll.
Updating libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.
Updating libstdc++-6.dll.
Updating libwinpthread-1.dll.
Creating directory accessible.
Updating qtaccessiblewidgets.dll.
Creating directory bearer.
Updating qgenericbearer.dll.
Updating qnativewifibearer.dll.
Creating directory iconengines.
Updating qsvgicon.dll.
Creating directory imageformats.
Updating qdds.dll.
Updating qgif.dll.
Updating qicns.dll.
Updating qico.dll.
Updating qjp2.dll.
Updating qjpeg.dll.
Updating qmng.dll.
Updating qsvg.dll.
Updating qtga.dll.
Updating qtiff.dll.
Updating qwbmp.dll.
Updating qwebp.dll.
Creating directory platforms.
Updating qwindows.dll.
Creating directory sqldrivers.
Updating qsqlite.dll.
Updating qsqlmysql.dll.
Updating qsqlodbc.dll.
Updating qsqlpsql.dll.
Creating qt_cs.qm...
Creating qt_de.qm...
Creating qt_fi.qm...
Creating qt_hu.qm...
Creating qt_it.qm...
Creating qt_ja.qm...
Creating qt_ru.qm...
Creating qt_sk.qm...
Creating qt_uk.qm...
0
>>>
```

Using `Anaconda2-4.2.0-Windows-x86.exe`:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:42:13) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>>
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>>
>>> environ          = os.environ.copy()
>>> environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join(['C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/mingw482_32/bin',
...                                                  'C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/bin'])
>>>
>>> subprocess.call(['C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/mingw482_32/bin/windeployqt',
...                  'release'], env=environ)
C:\Users\User\Downloads\git-dev\myapp\archive\MyApp-1.2-20170224083154\source\build\release\MyApp.exe 32 bit, release executable
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Widgets
All dependencies   : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Widgets
To be deployed     : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Widgets
Unable to find the platform plugin.
1
>>>
```

Why is it so?

Comment: You installed two seperate Python interpreters. Look here for conda package commands: https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html

Comment: I discovered anaconda python was not working when it was the only python interpreter in the environment. Afterwards I re-installed python for the tests, at this point in time I've used the full path to the python interpreter. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Then your anaconda is not installed properly, I'd guess.

Comment: Ideally I would like to use only anaconda. May I ask how to configure it correctly for the presented purposes?

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm running into the same issue

Comment: I don't remember exactly. I guess using the full path to the correct qmake might help.